# Merge two arrays in R alternating their elements

Tags: arrays, r, merge

Suppose I have two arrays of the same length (e.g. 1000), `array1` and `array2`, that look like

```
   array 1= 0.7828479 0.7782587 0.697296 0.7847533 0.7963145 0.7742886 0.6367928 ...
   array 2= 0.5324373 -0.5765472 -0.5020422 -0.3265736 -0.09438474 0.1368133 ...
```

and I want to merge them into a new array that looks like:

```
   first 20 elements of array 1 (i.e. array1[1], array1[2],...,array1[20])
   first 10 elements of array 2 (i.e. array2[1], array2[2],...,array2[10])
   second 20 elements of array 1 (i.e. array1[21], array1[2],...,array1[40])
   second 10 elements of array 2 (i.e. array2[11], array2[2],...,array2[20])
```

and so on, until all the elements of one of the arrays had been used up. Then `array1` will always be used up first and the resulting vector will have 20 and 10 consecutive items from array 1 and 2 respectively each time.

Comment: Can you clarify this more? do you mean vector or (multidimensional) array? I am also not sure what you mean by "and so on"; do you mean 20 and 10 consecutive items from array 1 and 2 respectively each time? Then array 1 will always be used up first, right? (you mentioned they are equal length)

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum, thanks for the questions. I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use vectors then. Does this work? (I use some randomly initialized vectors). This assumes that the size of your vectors is a multiple of the number of elements you want to take each time.

```
vec1 <- rnorm(100)
vec2 <- rnorm(100)
step1 <- 20
step2 <- 10
as.vector(sapply(0 : (length(vec1) / step1 - 1), function(idx){
  c(vec1[1 : step1 + (idx * step1)], vec2[1 : step2 + (idx * step2)])}))
```

Comment: Thank you @MartijnVanAttekum